# Changing properties of a TabControl when Custom UserControls embedded within it performs an action

Tags: c#, wpf

So, picture the situation...

I have a MainWindow, with a TabControl, *Apadtly named TabControl1*, placed within it. The TabControl is made up of 2 "tabs".

The first tab, contains an instantiation of one of my Custom User Controls, **FruitForm**, this particular instantiation is named *FruitForm1*.

Likewise the second tab contains an instantion of another one of my Custom User Control, **VegForm**, this particular instantiation is named *VegForm1*.

To give you an impression of what **FruitForm** and **VegForm** look like I have included the following image:

[I don't have enough rep to embed images within my question :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUGbr.png)

I also have 2 Validation classes named **FruitValidation** and **VegValidation** which are essentially made up of simple public static methods which return true or false depending on whether the input string matches the simple criteria. For example, consider the "**FruitValidation.validateApple()**" method:

```
public static bool validateApple(string apple)
    {
        if (apple == null) return false;

        if (apple.ToUpper() == "APPLE") return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

I also have an static **IconLoader** class, which is essentially a wrapper, which allows me to easily change the source property of my desired icon to a *Tick* or a *Cross*. For example if I wanted to change the icon next to the Banana textbox (see image above) to a *Tick* then I would write the following code:

```
imageBanana.Source = IconLoader.GetTick();

//setting it back to a cross...
imageBanana.Source = IconLoader.GetCross();
```

Everytime the text is changed within a particular textbox I validate whether the contents of the textbox matches the desired value. If it does I set the icon to a *Tick* otherwise it displays a *Cross*.

[This image should clarify what I have described in the previous paragraph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n115.png)

Now essentially this is the question:

**How do I change the image found within the header to a *Tick* when all textboxes within it's corresponding UserControl are valid (i.e. every TextBox has a *Tick* next to it)? I also want this particular event to be triggered from within the UserControl, which is not currently aware of *TabControl1's* exsistance**

*I should also point out that if one of the textfields were to become invalid (after being once valid at some point) the corresponding Tab header should reflect this - by displaying a Cross*

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer your question: the easiest way is to define a dependency property on your UserControls which will indicate the validation result and then bind your tab item to it. For example:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsValidProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsValid", typeof (bool), typeof (VegForm));
public bool IsValid
{
    get { return (bool) GetValue(IsValidProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsValidProperty, value); }
}

<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <Image>
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <!-- Replace "..." with valid "tick" image source -->
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="..."/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsValid, ElementName=VegForm}" Value="False">
                            <!-- Replace "..." with valid "cross" image source -->
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="..."/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <VegForm x:Name="VegForm"/>
</TabItem>
```

However, if your goal is to learn wpf - you should get rid of this `Windows.Forms` mentality before it takes you any further. Because normally you would not need this code. Reading a few articles on MVVM pattern in WPF is a good start.

Also WPF has an inbuild validation. You should read on that as well. Before you end up reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thank you got your fast and detailed response, it is much appriciated.

Comment: Now, please forgive my lack of knowledge, I have made the assumption that the C# part of the code wants to go inside my MainWindow.cs file. and that the XAML style code wants to replace a part of my MainWindow.xaml file.
I have done that, however I'm still not getting the desired output. I can only assume you may have overestimated my knowledge and left out pieces of code that may have seemed too obvious to mention. It may be worth mentioning that up until a few hours ago I'd never heard of a "Dependancy Property".

Comment: the type to which dependency property belongs is the third argument of `DependencyProperty.Register` method. So in my example, it should be declared in code-behind of your `VegForm` control (you will need to declare similar property in your `FruitForm` as well). Also dont foget to actually set its value in your `validate` methods.